# How to see which game a user is playing in Discord.JS v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, discord, discord.js

I am developing a discord bot by taking help from online guides. The problem is, the guides are mostly Discord.JS v11 guides and I am using Discord.JS v12. So it isn't helping me much. I want to find out how to get the name of the game a user is playing on !userinfo command. All the fields show correct stuff in them except the Game field. I have enabled the show presence thing in the developer portal. It always shows None in it, although maybe it is because its not a verified game name or something like Zoom Classes(XD) or something thats not verified. Can you tell me the fix? Code:

```
            case "userinfo":
                commandsrun = commandsrun + 1;
                let user;
                if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
                    user = message.mentions.users.first();
                    useralso = message.mentions.users.first();
                } else {
                    user = message.author;
                    useralso = message.member;
                    //i made useralso so it shows nickname correctly
                }
                const userStatus = {
                    online: "Online",
                    idle: "Idle/Inactive",
                    dnd: "Busy/Do Not Disturb",
                    offline: "Unavailable/Offline"
                }
                const mememb = message.guild.member(user)
                Promise.resolve(mememb).then(function () {
                    const memberemb = message.guild.members.fetch(user);
                    Promise.resolve(memberemb).then(function (info) {
                        var roles = info.roles.cache.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', ');
                        roles = roles.slice(0, -9);
                        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor("GREEN")
                            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
                            .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
                            .addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
                            .addField("Nickname:", `${useralso.nickname ? `${useralso.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
                            .addField("Status:", `${userStatus[user.presence.status]}`, true)
                            .addField("Game:", `${user.presence.game ? user.presence.game.name : 'None'}`, true)
                            .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(mememb.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
                            .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
                            .addField("Roles:", info.roles.cache ? roles : "None", true)
                            .setFooter(`Replying to ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
                        message.channel.send({ embed });
                    });
                });
                break;
```

Please tell me the fix and send the fixed code in your answer as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as you already told you are using discord.js v12 you need to use the `activities` property from the `Presence` class. Here is what you have to do -

```js
user.presence.activities[0].name // this will output the game or any other activity
```

But if the user is using a custom status then you might get the `Name` as undefined to solve this we need to filter the array !

```js
var presence = user.presence.activities.filter(x=>x.type === "PLAYING") //outputs the presence which the user is playing
presence[0].name // will give the name of the game
```

Your final Output should be -

```js
            case "userinfo":
                commandsrun = commandsrun + 1;
                let user;
                if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
                    user = message.mentions.users.first();
                    useralso = message.mentions.users.first();
                } else {
                    user = message.author;
                    useralso = message.member;
                    //i made useralso so it shows nickname correctly
                }
                const userStatus = {
                    online: "Online",
                    idle: "Idle/Inactive",
                    dnd: "Busy/Do Not Disturb",
                    offline: "Unavailable/Offline"
                }
                const mememb = message.guild.member(user)
                Promise.resolve(mememb).then(function () {
                   var presence = user.presence.activities.length ?user.presence.activities.filter(x=>x.type === "PLAYING") : null;
                    const memberemb = message.guild.members.fetch(user);
                    Promise.resolve(memberemb).then(function (info) {
                        var roles = info.roles.cache.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', ');
                        roles = roles.slice(0, -9);
                        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor("GREEN")
                            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
                            .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
                            .addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
                            .addField("Nickname:", `${useralso.nickname ? `${useralso.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
                            .addField("Status:", `${userStatus[user.presence.status]}`, true)
                            .addField("Game:", `${presence && presence.length ? presence[0].name : 'None'}`, true)
                            .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(mememb.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
                            .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
                            .addField("Roles:", info.roles.cache ? roles : "None", true)
                            .setFooter(`Replying to ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
                        message.channel.send({ embed });
                    });
                });
                break;
```

Comment: If you are getting an error `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` , this is due to the recent gateway changes consider reading this - https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html